# angularjs html5 application with web api windows authentication

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

I'm making a mobile app using web api 2 as a back end with an angularjs/html5 front end. As a result, razor is out.

I've found a bunch of third party log in solutions but nothing specific for windows authentication. I wound up restarting my web api project to "individual user Accounts" instead of "windows authentication" since that seems to automatically put in oWin and oAuth. But I'm unsure of where to go from there.

I feel like this is something simple that I'm missing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure your WebAPI and IIS to support Windows Authentication.

I assume that you had included

```html
<authentication mode="windows">
```

in Web.Config of WebAPI. Hope IIS is also configured appropriately.

And when you call your WebAPI from HTML (say $.ajax or equivalent) make sure you include

```js
 xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
```

in that call.

Comment: So in the end I wound up recreating my project for windows authentication. Since I was testing my mobile app remotely, I had setup a local IIS server that was not configured for windows authentication. IE it didn't have the provisions installed for it. Regardless if the web.config had the windows authentication flag, it wouldn't do it if the provisions weren't installed. After that, the above code worked for me. Hopefully it holds true through vpn connections.

I think I was looking for a more complicated solution to my problems. KISS